# How to correct Ref-time in nc file?

Tags: python, r, time, reference, cdo-climate

As it is shown in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2JoT.png) , my data starts from 1980-01-01 00:00:00. I would like my ref time to be the first time entry i.e. 1980-01-01. But instead the ref time is 1900-01-01 00:00:00. As the calendar is gregorian, i tried to change the calendar to standard format by using these two different commands and both works

```
ncatted -a calendar,time,o,c,standard in.nc out.nc
```

or

```
cdo setcalendar,standard in.nc out.nc
```

It changes the calendar:gregorian to calendar:standard but ref time is still 1900:01:01 as shown in the pic [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9o2Un.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9o2Un.png)
Need help in this regard.
I am using cdo, R, and python.
How can I correct the ref time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the reference time with

```
cdo setreftime,date in.nc out.nc
```

[See this link for details in the online manual](https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/embedded/index.html#x1-2550002.6.4)

Just to lastly mention that the `reftime` should be arbitrary for most purposes. Usually one only needs to change the ref time if it is specified by a data protocol (i.e. you want to upload model output to a model intercomparison project and they specify that they want a specific reftime) - the fact that the reftime is not the first timeslice's date is usually not an issue, the dates will still be correct.